# difficulty to plot a hist of chi-square~(1) over a simulated chi-square confidence interval

Tags: r

I am trying to code example 10.3.2 from statistical inference by casella. ( I attached the example here ).

[image: .]

I have issue with producing the same plot.  any help?

to simulate the data and  the comparison table:

```
 n=25
lam<-5
nsim<-10000
set.seed(442256)                   

poisson<-function(nsim,n,lam){
    ratio<-c()

distributionMean = NULL
for (i in 1 : nsim) distributionMean = c(distributionMean, mean(rpois( n, lam))) 

 d<- 2*n*((lam-distributionMean)-distributionMean*log(lam/distributionMean))
        ratio<-c(ratio,d)
        return(ratio )
    }

logLi<-poisson(10000,25,5)

m<-matrix(0,2, 4)
m[1,1]=quantile(p1,0.80)
m[2,1]=qchisq(.80, df=1)

m[1,2]=quantile(p1,0.90)
m[2,2]=qchisq(.90, df=1)

m[1,3]=quantile(p1,0.95)
m[2,3]=qchisq(.95, df=1)

m[1,4]=quantile(p1,0.99)
m[2,4]=qchisq(.99, df=1)
    row.names(m)<-c("simulated", "Chi-square")
    colnames(m)<-c("80_perc", "90_perc","95_perc","99_perc")
```

Comment: it looks like p1 variable is used before being assigned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want the table?  Try this.

```
simulated <- quantile(logLi, c(0.8, 0.9, 0.95, 0.99))
chisquare <- qchisq(c(0.8, 0.9, 0.95, 0.99), df = 1)

rbind(simulated, chisquare)
```

And the code for the graph is below.

```
a <- hist(logLi, freq=FALSE, xlim = c(0,4), 
          breaks = seq(0, ceiling(max(logLi)), by = 0.1))
lines(a$mids, dchisq(a$mids, df = 1))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for cleaning my table and helping ,e with the graph! It works***:)